# Checking if a line in a file contains user.Handle and '-r'+any single digit number

Tags: c#, search

The title pretty much explains everything. I'm try to check if a line in a file contains `user.Handle` and '`-r`'+any single digit number, AND that the aforementioned `user.Handle` does not contain '`-r`'. I'm sure there is an easier way to do this. And I'm sorry if this made your eyes bleed.

```
if (line.Contains(user.Handle) && !user.Handle.Contains("-r") &&
line.Contains("-r1") || line.Contains(user.Handle) &&
!user.Handle.Contains("-r") && line.Contains("-r2") ||
line.Contains(user.Handle) && !user.Handle.Contains("-r") &&
line.Contains("-r3") || line.Contains(user.Handle) &&
!user.Handle.Contains("-r") && line.Contains("-r4") ||
line.Contains(user.Handle) && !user.Handle.Contains("-r") &&
line.Contains("-r5") || line.Contains(user.Handle) &&
!user.Handle.Contains("-r") && line.Contains("-r6") ||
line.Contains(user.Handle) && !user.Handle.Contains("-r") &&
line.Contains("-r7") || line.Contains(user.Handle) &&
!user.Handle.Contains("-r") && line.Contains("-r8") ||
line.Contains(user.Handle) && !user.Handle.Contains("-r") &&
line.Contains("-r9"))
```

Comment: Are you trying to parse command line arguments? There might be some libraries that make that even easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I see it correctly, you could already simplify your code by saying

```
if (line.Contains(user.Handle) && !user.Handle.Contains("-r") &&
    (line.Contains("-r1") || line.Contains("-r2") || ... line.Contains("-r9"))
```

That should be basically the same thing as the above. Now when you look at the last part, you could simplify it to a regular expression `-r\d` (not sure if `-` needs to be escaped here) So the final version could look like this:

```
if (line.Contains(user.Handle) && !user.Handle.Contains("-r") &&
    Regex.IsMatch(line, "-r\\d"))
```

did I get your question? Did I miss anything?

Comment: Wow, I never knew regex could be so useful. Thank you so much for your answer. Learned a lot today

Comment: You can use `IsMatch` also as a static method.

Comment: @t3chb0t I was looking for it, but obviously not thoroughly enough - thx for pointing it out, I've updated the code

Comment: If the code is executed frequently, consider to use regex option `RegexOptions.Compiled` to improve performance.

Comment: This is a very old post from 2005: https://blog.codinghorror.com/to-compile-or-not-to-compile/ -  but I've seen often people saying that you shouldn't use the compile option unless you know what you're doing.